# Usar os atributos unários de Tags HTML com valor atribuido

Tags: html

Exite diferença entre usar os atributos `unários` de forma alternativa (com um valor)? como por  exemplo:

Forma padrão:

```
<script src="/js/" defer></script>
```

Forma alternativa 1:

```
<script src="/js/" defer="defer"></script>
```

Forma alternativa 2:

```
<script src="/js/" defer=true></script>
```

Forma alternativa 3:

```
<script src="/js/" defer="true"></script>
```

Será executado de forma idêntica a padrão? (outros atributos também são unários como o `disabled`).

Comment: sim, mas testei com outro atributo não com o defer

Comment: adicionei um exemplo da criação do atributo através de javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo o [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), "This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that[...]" ou em português "Este atributo booleano é setado para indicar ao browser que[...]". Ou seja, afirmamos que o atributo é booleano.

Segundo essa resposta do usuário *Chuck* de uma pergunta similar porém no [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089584/html-why-boolean-attributes-do-not-have-boolean-value), referente a atributo `selected`:

"In SGML, an attribute may be minimized so that its value alone is short for both the name and the value, with the only possible value for the attribute in this case obviously being the attribute's own name. HTML uses this for boolean attributes, where the presence or absence of the attribute is what's meaningful, and its value is irrelevant [...] You can just write selected."

Basicamente o que ele quis dizer associando com o seu caso:

Em SGML (*Standard Generalized Markup Language*), um atributo pode ser minimizado para o valor sozinho quando *name* e o *value* são os mesmo, nesse caso obviamente, você utiliza apenas o *name* do atributo (no seu caso utilize apenas `defer`). O HTML utiliza essa forma para atributos booleanos em que a presença do valor ou não é irrelevante (no caso de `true` ou `defer`). Ou seja, você pode apenas escrever `defer`.

Confirmando o que *Chuck* descreve, segundo a [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html) a respeito de SGML e HTML: "Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the attribute itself" ou "Atributos booleanos podem assumir legalmente um único valor: o *name* do próprio atributo".

Ainda no mesmo documento: "Some attributes play the role of boolean variables[...]. Their appearance in the start tag of an element implies that the value of the attribute is *true*.

"Alguns atributos desempenham o papel de variáveis booleanas[...]. Sua aparição na marca de início de um elemento implica que o valor do atributo é *true*.

Ou seja, quando o elemento está declarado é o mesmo que dizer que seu valor é *true*:

`<script src="/js/" defer></script>`

`<script src="/js/" defer="true"></script>`

`<script src="/js/" defer="defer"></script>`

`<script src="/js/" defer=""></script>`

Todas essas declarações são validas, porém conforme tudo o que foi dito acima recomenda-se usar a primeira alternativa.

---

Um fato interessante é que quando se utiliza javascript, mas precisamente o *setAttribute* para criar esses atributos você precisa necessária passar dois parâmetros sendo eles *name* e *value*, e nesse caso você pode tanto passar o valor de *true*, quanto o valor vazio:

`setAttribute('defer', '');` ou `setAttribute('defer', 'true');`

Uma dica, para atributos HTML utilize o *value* sempre dentro de " ", essa é a forma padrão da linguagem.